# What does AVEncoderAudioQualityKey do?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

According to the scanty docs, the `AVEncoderAudioQualityKeys` are --

> Keys that specify sample rate conversion quality, used
>       for the AVSampleRateConverterAudioQualityKey property.
>
> ```
> enum {
>    AVAudioQualityMin       = 0,
>    AVAudioQualityLow       = 0x20,
>    AVAudioQualityMedium    = 0x40,
>    AVAudioQualityHigh      = 0x60,
>    AVAudioQualityMax       = 0x7F
> };
> typedef NSInteger AVAudioQuality;
> ```

Testing with AVAudioRecorder, there is virtually no difference in resulting audio file size or quality for a 2 minute recording recorded with `AVAudioQualityMin` versus one recorded with `AVAudioQualityMax`. The test used an 8KHz sample rate using `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC`.

Can someone enlighten me as to the theoretical and practical purpose of this key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These keys are used for specifying quality in sample rate conversions. Audio file format, which specifies the sample rate and bit depth, determines your file size. [According to the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationAudioSettings_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009937-CH2-SW12) they are:

> Keys that specify sample rate conversion quality, used for the
>   [AVSampleRateConverterAudioQualityKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationAudioSettings_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/AVSampleRateConverterAudioQualityKey) property.

So, these quality keys only determine how well you want to re-sample audio into another format.

[read more](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationAudioSettings_Constants/Reference/reference.html)